# HTML5 CSS Video Tag inside div

Tags: css, html

I im using bootstrap modal plugin that i want to put to background animated mp4 video...how can i put in modal that so that video is shows from top to bottom in modal dialog..i have this html code:

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="user" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <!-- page videocontent -->
    <video preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" width="640" height="480">
            <!-- video files -->
            <source src="./vid/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="./vid/1.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="./vid/1.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
    <!-- modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <div class="modal-header-left">
                <h3>Add User</h3>
                <p>Enter username, password, bouquet, expire to create user:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-header-right">
                <i class="fa fa-user-pencil fa-2x"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <!-- form username -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username" class="control-label">Username *</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control parsley-validated" id="username" parsley-trigger="change" parsley-required="true" parsley-minlength="4" parsley-validation-minlength="1">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- form password -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" class="control-label">Password *</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control parsley-validated" id="password" parsley-trigger="change" parsley-required="true" parsley-minlength="4" parsley-validation-minlength="1">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- form mac -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!-- label mac -->
                    <label for="mac" class="control-label">MAC</label>
                    <!-- input mac -->
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control parsley-validated" id="mac" parsley-trigger="change" parsley-minlength="4" parsley-type="mac" parsley-validation-minlength="1">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- form expire -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!-- label expire -->
                    <label for="expire" class="control-label">Expire *</label>
                    <!-- input expire -->
                    <div class="col-sm-8" id="expire">
                        <select class="chosen-select chosen-transparent form-control parsley-validated" id="expire" parsley-trigger="change" parsley-required="true" parsley-error-container="#selectbox" style="display: none;">
                            <option value="">Please choose</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                        </select><div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-container-single-nosearch" style="width: 0px;" title="" id="expire_chosen"><a class="chosen-single" tabindex="-1"><span>3</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chosen-drop"><div class="chosen-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" readonly=""></div><ul class="chosen-results"><li class="active-result result-selected" style="" data-option-array-index="0">Please choose</li><li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">1</li><li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="2">2</li><li class="active-result result-selected" style="" data-option-array-index="3">3</li><li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="4">4</li><li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="5">5</li></ul></div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- form bouquet -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!-- label bouquet -->
                    <label for="bouquet" class="control-label">Bouquet *</label>
                    <!-- input bouquet -->
                    <div class="col-sm-8" id="bouquet">
                        <select class="chosen-select chosen-transparent form-control parsley-validated" id="bouquet" parsley-trigger="change" parsley-required="true" parsley-error-container="#selectbox" style="display: none;">
                            <option value="">Please choose</option>
                            <option value="1">BOUQUET1</option>
                            <option value="2">BOUQUET2</option>
                            <option value="3">BOUQUET3</option>
                        </select><div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-container-single-nosearch" style="width: 0px;" title="" id="bouquet_chosen"><a class="chosen-single" tabindex="-1"><span>BOUQUET4</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chosen-drop"><div class="chosen-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" readonly=""></div><ul class="chosen-results"><li class="active-result result-selected" style="" data-option-array-index="0">Please choose</li><li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">Ex-Yu</li><li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="2">Mega</li><li class="active-result result-selected" style="" data-option-array-index="3">MAG250 MEGA</li></ul></div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- form notes -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!-- label notes -->
                    <label for="notes" class="control-label">Notes</label>
                    <!-- textbox notes -->
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <textarea class="form-control parsley-validated" id="notes" rows="3" parsley-trigger="keyup" parsley-rangelength="[0,200]" parsley-validation-minlength="1"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- form options -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!-- label options -->
                    <label class="control-label">Options</label>
                    <!-- checkbox options -->
                    <div class="col-sm" id="options">
                        <div class="checkbox check-transparent">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="adult" parsley-group="adult" parsley-trigger="change" parsley-required="true" parsley-mincheck="2" parsley-error-container="#adult .last" class="parsley-validated parsley-error">
                            <label for="adult">Adult</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <!-- modal-footer buttons -->
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">OK</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default cancel">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i need to show video tag in modal-dialog modal-sm class so that video is displayed in whole modal, i set in video tag width: 640 and height 480 but it is shows only in modal-body class and i don't know how to expand whole video object to whole div object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

add this to your CSS File:

```
    .videoAdd {
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto; 
    height: auto; 
    z-index: -100;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and in HTML file try adding this Div and add the video tag inside it:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <video class="videoAdd">
  <source src="yourVideoSrc" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="anotherVideoSrc" type="video/ogg">
 </video>
</div>
```